# can we remove default layout of view in yii 1.1

Tags: php, yii

I am new in yii, and trying to import a existing PHP site into this framework, so i want to remove default layout style of yii, just wanna show my view page.
Is there any way to do so?

like, when i load a view

```
$this->render('myview');
```

then only myview.php should be render.
I didn't found any help anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put `$this->layout = false;` in your action or a property `public $layout = false;` in your controller if you want it disabled controller wide.

Comment: Just understand, when you do this, you are removing one of the key advantages of using an MVC framework.  That is consistent page layout. You can still have a consistent page layout,  you just have to code it in each page.

Answer (score 1):

Use the renderPartial function.

```
$this->renderPartial('myview', array('model'=>$model));
```

You can do other things, like assign the markup to a variable and do things like echo, manipulate and save it.

The renderPartial will not load the page layout.

Answer (score -1):

// for disabled in whole controller actions use following method in controller

Class siteController extend controller {

Public $layout = false;

}

// disable for particular action in controller 
Class siteController extend controller {

```
Public actionIndex (){
       $this->layout = false.
 }
```

}